# Reduce IPA size for here flutter SDK

Tags: here-api

We integrated Here flutter sdk to use a single feature : offline map.
HOwever the app size becomes huge (around 200MO).
Is there anyway to optimize the app size please.

We tried removing the extra fonts but the impact is very small.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce the size, you can perform the steps mentioned here- https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.13.5.0/dev_guide/topics/optimization.html . After using Abi split the application size is reduced considerably.